# Use the division algorithm to establish that,The square of any integer can be written in one of the forms 3k or 3k + 1.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification

We can express
a² = 3k + r

since  0<=r<3
there are three possibilities
a² = 3k
a² = 3k + 1
a² = 3k + 2

If these possibilities true then (a²)² can be written in those forms
Hence
(a²)² = 9k = 3(3k)
(a²)² = (3k + 1)² = 3(3k² + 2k) + 1
same as above, this formats true for (a³)²,(a⁴)²......(aⁿ)²
these two forms can be accepted

but
(a²)² = (3k + 2)² = 3(3k² + 4) + 4 = 3(3k² + 4k + 1) + 1
3k + 2 format inclined to 3k + 1 format.
hence 3k + 2 is non-square number like 2,3,5,6....
in this case, 3k + 2 is not a general format for the square of an integer.

Therefore 3k + 2 cannot be accepted.

This is my proof. Is this correct? Then what are the right solutions?

Comment: Almost, but instead you need $a=3k+r$ not $a^2=3k+r$.

Comment: @Ray, Is this correct when I apply  a=3k+r instead of a²=3k+r for the same way?

Comment: As @Ray said you have to start with a=3k+r then write the possibilities for r and then calculating the answer for the second power would be enough

Comment: This had nothing to do with [tag:division-algebras]. Please read tag wikis before using them. I know that not all the common tags have proper wikis, but in this case it would have helped. If the tag wiki is all Greek to you, then don't use it.